# How to getting sum of Count() value that using groupBy in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, count, sum, grouping

I have a table with 2 fields:

```
Datetime                     [IndexValue]
---------                    -----------
2014-02-23 20:15:59.000      G
2014-02-23 20:15:59.000      G
2014-02-23 20:15:59.000      Y
2014-03-05 12:42:59.683      R
2014-03-05 12:42:59.683      G
2014-03-05 12:42:59.683      Y
2014-03-05 12:42:59.683      G
```

I want to group them by name, with 'count', and 'SUM'

```
Datetime                 [IndexValue] amount   total
---------                -----------  ------  ------
2014-02-23 20:15:59.000  G            2       3
2014-02-23 20:15:59.000  Y            1       3
2014-03-05 12:42:59.683  G            2       4
2014-03-05 12:42:59.683  Y            1       4
2014-03-05 12:42:59.683  R            1       4
```

I success with this code, but just in MySQL, error in SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(varchar,[CreateDate],101),[IndexValue],
COUNT(*) AS amount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM [db_spc].[dbo].[tb_crqs_item])
FROM [db_spc].[dbo].[tb_crqs_item]
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar,[CreateDate],101),[IndexValue]
ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar,[CreateDate],101)
```

How would I write a query in SQL Server?

Comment: I do not understand what your subquery is doing? (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM [db_spc].[dbo].[tb_crqs_item]).   It is counting all the records in table for every row of outside query? Can you clarify this?

Comment: cause if i use this : (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM [db_spc].[dbo].[tb_crqs_item] GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar,[CreateDate],101)). then there is an error "Subquery returned more than 1 value, not permitted"

Comment: Nice, a "guess what error I get with this code" competition. What is the reward?

Comment: I meant that how to calculate "Total"?

Comment: You say you get "error in SQL 2008" but not what the error is. You expect answerers to set up an sql server 2008 environment with test data and run your query to find out what the problem is? If you say what error you get it is much easier to get help.

Comment: Total is sum() of amount where the Datetime is same.

Comment: okay, i have problem in calculate amount and total in the same time. when i using groupby Datetime and indexValue i can calculate amount but can't calculate total..and if i using groupby Datetime i can calculate total but cant calculate amount.. so what should i do with my query ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a count of a subgroup, you need to link to the main table to identify that group.
ie:

```
SELECT 
    createdate,
    [IndexValue],
    COUNT(*) AS amount, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_crqs_item t1 where t1.createdate =t0.createdate)
FROM tb_crqs_item t0
GROUP BY createdate,[IndexValue]
ORDER BY createdate
```

Comment: okay, but that createdate have type data datetime ..if i want to get count /day? how to convert 'where t1.createdate =t0.createdate'